Why is there no audio when playing DVD?
I just bought a 2020 Escalade ESV last week. I insert a DVD or Blu-ray movie and it will eventually play on the 2nd and 3rd row ceiling screens. But NO AUDIO! Message says "Blu-ray / DVD Inserted Use Video Application". But I go to the "Apps" part of CUE and there is no video application. Other audio stuff works fine like radio, SiriusXM, Bluetooth, CarPlay, etc. Just not movies.
So what's wrong? Am I misinterpreting that message and there really is something I can use to make it stream the audio?
Is it missing an audio codec? How would I install that? I left the car on WiFi overnight and next day it said it had updated the "Apps", but no system updates.
I've tried all the volume controls. It didn't come with a video remote control. Is that required to get audio? Can't the massive UI and onscreen display handle this?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

For me, the solution was to disconnect the car battery and let it drain for about a half hour. Then when I hooked it back up the main menu on the CUE display now had a "Video" button, as well as the "Audio" and other buttons. When I pushed Video it played the DVD and all was well.
